# Ruby model generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page where by the users fills in the text fields, about 17 of them in fact. When I run the rails generate model do I require to put in all 17 (title:string). An example one is below. This is called customer. All my labels are different as i thought it may pay off when searching the databases later. I must be missing the point!

```
<%= f.label :customer, 'Customer:', :class=> 'label' %> <%= f.text_field :customer, :class => 'text_field', :size => 40 %>



<%= f. date_select :date, options= { order: [:day, :month, :year ]} %><br><br>
```

Comment: If you are asking if you have to enter all of the fields in the generate, yes you will need to in order for it to generate the model with the attributes and a matching migration.

Comment: ok does it matter that there are two drop down boxes and a text area? are they still referenced in the generate command as title:string ?

Comment: You will create a field for the drop down boxes, either a string or an integer probably and then have a Hash or array of values to populate the drop down.  For the text field use a text field type.

Comment: Look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag for building a select tag from an object

Comment: For textarea refer it as `fieldname:text` and for dropdown's as `fieldname:string`

Comment: ok I have added my date box above as part of my code. How is that referenced in the model generator for inclusion to the database.

Comment: Can you paste code in for the migration? Migration will be in `db/migrate`. If you are using `form_for` like I suspect then you need the Customer or whatever table to be actually created. By the way if you mess up the generate command (it might happen when you have to write the 17 fields) it's okay, just fix the migration file to include the missing fields.

Comment: OK I will do...  I need to go ahead with the 17 entries. Then migrate and then I will post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not necessary to write all 17 on terminal while creating model but before `rake db:migrate` you have to add all the 17 fields in migration file then only those will be added in database schema and you have to create form manually for all fields.

Comment: ok I have added all the forms and fields manually to the html output... using forms_for. Where is the migration file?

Comment: If you have run db:migrate already you have to write new migration for adding new fields and if you have not run db:migrate then you can add in existing migration .migration file would  be in db/migrate folder.